# Make separator optional in express router

Tags: regex, express, url-routing

My urls may either look like `/posts/sluggish-slug-postId123` or like `/posts/postId123`.

My router currently contains:

`router.get('/posts/:slug?-:id([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', function () {...}`

but using this regex the `-` in between the `slug` and the `id` is mandatory, which means I can't validate urls that only contain an `id` (e.g. `/posts/postId123`). How do I make the `-` separator optional along with keeping the `slug` optional?

**Paths that should match**

- `/posts/going-long-for-the-ball-3a6p412`

  - slug: `going-long-for-the-ball`
  - id: `3a6p412`
- `/posts/3a6p412`

  - slug: *not set*
  - id: `3a6p412`

**Paths that should *not* match**

- `/posts/-3a6p412`

Comment: Could you add some more examples of paths that should and shouldn't match and the desired values for `slug` and `id` for those that do match? It's currently quite difficult to tell what you're asking.

Comment: I still don't think I follow the (clarified) question.  Are you looking for `/posts/:(slug-)?whatever`?

Comment: I'm trying to validate any slug followed by a dash and an alphanumeric id. The slug is optional, and if the slug does not exist then the dash should not exist.

Comment: Okay, that's what my (uninformed) expression tries to do.

Comment: @wallyk I edited the question and believe it is more clarified. Does your comment give an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't quite get what you wanted but this comes close:

```
router.get('/posts/:slug([a-z][a-z\-]{0,}-|):id([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', function (req, res) {
```

The `slug` will include the trailing `-` if it's present and it will be an empty string if there is no slug. The section `[a-z][a-z\-]{0,}` ensures that the slug must start with a character in the range `a-z` and can then contain any number of characters from `a-z` or `-`. If your slugs can contain other characters you'd just need to adapt that part accordingly. Note that I'm using `{0,}` rather than `*` because of a quirk of how Express routes interprets `*`.

The way Express routes get converted to regular expressions is somewhat difficult to follow and there are major changes between Express 4 and 5 that make using complex expressions an unsafe bet for future compatibility. If you want to do something more complicated than the examples given in the documentation I would suggest just using an actual RegExp instead to cut out the unreliable middleman. Alternatively you could skip trying to parse/validate the URL in the route path altogether and do that inside your handler function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\/posts\/(?<slug>.+\-)?(?<id>\w+)$
```

Result:

```
/posts/going-long-for-the-ball-3a6p412 (match)
/posts/3a6p412 (match)
/posts/-3a6p412 (no match)
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/jLMzjM/2